# Check for blade.php in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Hello and do not be tired

Is there a way to check for a blade.php file in Laravel?

Because I want to check if the file exists before addressing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
if(view()->exists($view)){
    return view($view)->render();
}
return "404 page not found";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here how you can get know that file exists or not in Laravel

```
 if (\View::exists('some.view')) { 

 }
```

reference from this link
https://webdevetc.com/programming-tricks/laravel/laravel-blade/how-to-check-if-a-blade-view-file-exists/

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need this check because it is not a dynamic element. But if there is a reason you need to do it, you can simply use php's own function `file_exists("bla.blade.php");`. it will return true or false.

Answer (score 0):

To complete the answer of @kamran-khalid you can also include a partial in `blade` only when the view exists

```php
{{-- include `view.name` only if it exists --}}
@includeIf('view.name', ['status' => 'complete'])
```

```php
{{-- include the first partial that exists --}}
@includeFirst(['custom.admin', 'admin'], ['status' => 'complete'])
```

More information in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#including-subviews